# Cannot connect wireless internet with an Atheros AR9285 802.11b/g/n wi-fi adapter

Tags: 12.04, wireless, network-manager, atheros

I am new to Ubuntu, Am trying to connect to wireless network but in the network center i cannot even select a local network there are no listings, In windows its straight forward enter in a key, however, I cannot seem to get the wireless to respond. Any ideas?

Comment: Was the WI-FI card in the computer when you bought it?

Comment: ah for sure, i can connect with windows, so that would mean it would be there right?

Comment: well, if you bought it and then installed it, you would need to install drivers on Ubuntu to allow it to connect.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Could you add some more information about your computer and your network card? I would be helpful to  know what the exact name of your card is, what the name and brand of your computer is. This helps us to locate the problem and to give you a helpful answer.

Comment: ok, so i got Atheros AR9285 802.11b/g/n wi-fi adaptor

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, the network center does not show awailable wireless networks. To see those you have to click on the wifi-symbol at the right top corner of your display.

[image: wifi-symbol]

Then you are able to choose the network, you want to connect and Ubuntu will ask you for the wifi-key.